Does Payoneer send this kind of email after account creation?
A week ago i created an account on Payoneer, and a few hours later i received an email asking for details like:

the reasons of the international transactions
how much i was intending to move into the account per month
and when i would do my first transaction.

It tells that it's a required step for activating the account, but when i searched the web to find out whether other people also received this email, i found nothing, and i'm kinda paranoid about this kind of stuff, so i would like to know if that's normal.
Edit:. It's actually the second time i receive that kind of email from the same sender which identifies himself as a sales executive. Here is a print of the email, and although it's written in portuguese, which is my native language, it tells everything i already explained.

Is it reasonable for Payoneer (or any bank) to ask you these questions and make providing answers a requirement of opening your account? Yes - I have been asked similar questions on opening a bank account with a well-known and respected bank in the UK, it's part of their KYC (Know Your Customer) processes.
Is it reasonable for Payoneer (or any bank) to ask you these questions via email and expect you to respond with the information via email? No. Email is inherently insecure and personal information like this should not be requested or provided via email.
The email you received may or may not have come from Payoneer, you'd need someone who understands these things to scrutinise the headers and determine. If you post the full email with headers here (any personal information redacted) we can have a look and see. But the only sensible way to respond to such an email is to log into your Payoneer account - NOT using any links provided in the email, going direct to Payoneer website - and see if they are seeking this information from you through the site.

Thanks a lot for your answer! I almost answered the email, but i found really suspicious that, when accessing my account via the website or the app, i find nothing about the additional configuration steps mentioned in the email. However, the email domain seems legit. I just edited the post including a print.

We'd need to see the email headers, not the content of the email.

(anyone can send an email "from" president@whitehouse.gov or support@payoneer.com...)
